# How do you properly do string.at(i)=="a" in C++

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

I am trying to compare a string element with a one element literal.

What is the proper and orthodox way to do this in C++?

Comment: Use single quotes.

Comment: What are the "elements" in a *string* ? Try comparing to a `char` rather than another string. I.e. `'a'`

Comment: Lesson for the day, `'x'` - is a *Character Literal*, `"x"` or, e.g. `"xxxxx"` is a *String Literal*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both comments suggested, something as simple as using single quotes.